# Any Oozie equivalent feature in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Is there anything similar to Oozie in Spark for workflow design. I have a use case where I have to query on hive for every 5mins interval.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oozie is getting a native Spark action with [this Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1983) so if you're prepared to wait for the next release or run Oozie trunk, then this might be an option.